# Add one for every row that fulfills where criteria between period

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a Postgres table that I'm trying to analyze based on some date columns.

I'm basically trying to count the number of rows in my table that fulfill this requirement, and then group them by month and year. Instead of my query looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE date1::date <= '2012-05-31' 
                       and date2::date > '2012-05-31';
```

it should be able to display this for the months available in my data so that I don't have to change the months manually every time I add new data, and so I can get everything with one query.

In the case above I'd like it to group the sum of rows which fit the criteria into the year 2012 and month 05. Similarly, if my WHERE clause looked like this:

```
date1::date <= '2012-06-31' and date2::date > '2012-06-31'
```

I'd like it to group this sum into the year 2012 and month 06.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't entirely clear to me:

> I'd like it to group the sum of rows

I'll interpret it this way: you want to list all rows "per month" matching the criteria:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('month', min(date1)) AS start
          ,date_trunc('month', max(date2)) + interval '1 month' AS stop
    FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT to_char(y.mon, 'YYYY-MM') AS mon, t.*
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(x.start, x.stop, '1 month') AS mon
   FROM   x
   ) y
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.date1::date <= y.mon 
                 AND t.date2::date >  y.mon   -- why the explicit cast to date?
ORDER  BY y.mon, t.date1, t.date2;
```

Assuming `date2 >= date1`.

1. Compute lower and upper border of time period and truncate to month (adding 1 to upper border to include the last row, too.
2. Use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to create the set of months in question
3. `LEFT JOIN` rows from your table with the declared criteria and sort by month.

You could also `GROUP BY` at this stage to calculate aggregates ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reasoning.  First, create a list of all possible dates.  Then get the cumulative number of date1 up to a given date.  Then get the cumulative number of date2 after the date and subtract the results.  The following query does this using correlated subqueries (not my favorite construct, but handy in this case):

```
select thedate,
       (select count(*) from t where date1::date <= d.thedate) -
       (select count(*) from t where date2::date > d.thedate)
from (select distinct thedate
      from ((select date1::date as thedate from t) union all
            (select date2::date as thedate from t)
           ) d
     ) d
```

This is assuming that date2 occurs after date1.  My model is start and stop dates of customers.  If this isn't the case, the query might not work.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you could benefit from the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) T-SQL method.  If I understand you correctly, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, date1) Year, DATEPART(month, date1) Month, SUM(value_col)
FROM $Table
-- WHERE CLAUSE ?
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, date1),
  DATEPART(month, date1)
```

Comment: Or even it's [PostgreSQL equivalent](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), `date_part('year', date1)` and `date_part('month', date1)`...

Comment: There is no `DATEPART` in PostgreSQL, this answer is misplaced.